# Radio button with "uniform" directive doesn't set to ng-checked

Tags: angularjs, uniform

This works (the button is checked by default):

```
<input type="radio" name="xyz" ng-model="formData.foo" ng-checked="true" value="bar">
```

This doesn't work (the button is not checked by default):

```
<input uniform type="radio" name="xyz" ng-model="formData.foo" ng-checked="true" value="bar">
```

What's the problem?

EDIT:

This works (changed `ng-checked` to `checked`):

```
<input uniform type="radio" name="xyz" ng-model="formData.foo" checked="true" value="bar">
```

Is this a proper way of doing things like this?

EDIT2:

I'd prefer to have the `ng-checked` attribute, as this would allow me to evaluate expressions.

Comment: Its a js library for styling form elements see http://uniformjs.com/#example

Comment: Alternatively, you can check radio inside controller --> `$scope.formData.foo = 'bar';`

Comment: To check the problem why it's not working, you can open browser's console and select error tab and reload the page. Check for any errors.

Comment: see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D, `ng-checked` doesn't work on radio type input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check radio inside the controller.

```
  $scope.formData.foo = 'bar';
```

According to [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D), `ng-checked` argument is not applicable on radio type input tag.